# Force shorthand chained expression on void functions?

Tags: c#

I'd like to take

```
var form = getForm();  //returns Form type
form.Show();
form.BringToFront();
```

and make it short-hand as much as possible. Unfortunately I can't chain the expressions like I could in LINQ since `Show()` and `BringToFront()` don't return the original Form object. Is there a way to get around this to produce code like:

```
getForm().Show().BringToFront()
```

An Extension method might work for Form but in this particular case `getForm()` returns sub-classes of Form.

Comment: Add a ShowAndBringToFront() method?

Comment: That's one solution but then I would be writing a function for every chained expression I wanted.

Comment: *"getForm() returns sub-classes of Forms"*. And why does that make extension methods unapplicable?

Comment: @InBetween I just made an edit, I was mistaken about the extension method not working on sub-classes as I had tried before but a different posted question lead me astray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this extension maybe:

```
public static T Do<T>(this T obj, params Action<T>[] actions)
{
    foreach(var action in actions)
        action(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

...

```
getForm().Do(f => f.Show()).Do(f => f.BringToFront());
```

you could also perform multiple actions without chaining:

```
getForm().Do(f => f.Show(), f => f.BringToFront());
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because your `getForm()` method returns a subclass of `Form` doesn't mean you can't create an extension method. You'll just need to set it to the `Form` class. This will put it on all derivations of the `Form` class within your project.

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    // Slightly shorter name
    public static Form ShowAndFront(this Form form)
    {
        form.Show();
        form.BringToFront();

        return form;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better might be to `return form;` as the last line?

Comment: @mjwills Good call!

Comment: I had this before but I did it wrong. However a means to chain expressions would be a lot more fun than writing more extension functions

Comment: @Zorgarath Except you can't do that on void methods. Fluent syntax wasn't created (at least in C#) until WinForms was falling out of favor. Because of that, they never updated the library to eliminate most of their methods to return the form object.

Comment: Is there something better than WinForms to be using?

Comment: WPF was the successor to WinForms. I'm not sure if that has the ability for fluent syntax, but it would be far more likely. It was introduced with .NET 3.0, and LINQ was 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class FluentExtensions
{
    public static T FluentInvoke<T>(this T o, Action<T> toInvoke)
    {
        toInvoke(o);
        return o;
    }
}
```

You then use it like so (note that `Sort` normally doesn't return the `List`):

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<int> {1, 3, 2};

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list.FluentInvoke(o => o.Sort())));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

or in your case:

```
getForm().FluentInvoke(z => z.Show()).FluentInvoke(z => z.BringToFront());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the extension method approach work by turning your extension method generic:

```
T ShowForm<T>(this T form) where T : Form {
    form.Show();
    return form;
}
```

Now you can write

```
GetForm().ShowForm().BringToFront();
```

Comment: and now he needs to do a third action with the form, what then?

Comment: @TimSchmelter If OP wants to chain the non-chainable methods, he'd need to provide wrappers for all of them.